# How can I change my Ajax to call two files with this code?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm new to AJAX, and I think I have a grasp on how it works. I created an edit profile form script using a tutorial and it works fine but I would also like for it to reload a php include file so that changes are automatically reloaded without going to another page.

So right now, when a form is submitted, it calls a php script I wrote named tehloader.php that makes changes to my database.

Everything works fine but I would also like for it to refresh an include file named brain.php that is on every page. This include file has a theme feature. So if a member would change the color of the theme using edit profile, I would like the brain.php to refresh so that the color changes to what tehloader.php changed in the database when they hit save.

Here's my code.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function ajax_post(){
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "tehloader.php?load=profile";
var nm = document.getElementById("nname").value;
var cr = document.getElementById("color").value;
var pf = document.getElementById("styled").value;
var tk = document.getElementById("token").value;
var acc = document.getElementById("access").value;
var vars = "nnname="+nm+"&nnnprofile="+pf+"&ncolor="+cr+"&acccess="+acc+"&tokken="+tk;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
var return_data = hr.responseText;
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
}
}
hr.send(vars);
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<img src=./ajax-loader.gif>";
}
</script>
```

So is this possible to do? Thanks.

Comment: If `brain.php` chooses what css to display eg the colours from the users choice, then the css is already loaded in the browser, a refresh is required to update the css, you could create a new ajax request that retrieves the updated version of the css and then apply that or make a new js function that alters the current `colours` based on the users selection once submitted, then there is no need to make that new ajax call to brain.php

Comment: Are you comfortable using javascript library like jQuery? or
Willing to use jQuery. If yes then I can suggest you the approach and help you with the code

Comment: Well `brain.php` looks at the members table for a color name. Here is an example of the way I have it. `if($members['Theme']=="Default")
{
$themeview = 'vblue';
$themeboomview = 'bblue';
$themelining = 'lblue';
$contentcolor = 'cblue';
$menutheme = 'xmenu.js';
}`

Comment: Notice that vblue, bblue, lblue, cblue are different div names and xmenu.js is a javascript menu. The theme system just changes the divs and menu depending on what theme they have. Would I still need a refresh of the css, using my current method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind AJAX calls is that the server call happens in the background and the current page is not reloaded, which results in faster operation and more dynamic and responsive interfaces.

When you get the return value of an AJAX call, it is the javascript calling code's responsibility to update any UI elements to reflect the changes, since the full page is not going to be reloaded.

In your case, from what I understand, you want to reflect changes in the user's theme preferences. In this specific scenario, you should consider if you really need AJAX behaviour here, since you essentially want to refresh the whole page (with new colours etc). Depending on the amount of theming and how you implement it, you can either update the UI in javascript to the new theme (which could be tedious,possibly loading CSS on the fly and etc) or maybe consider simply refreshing the page with a full POST or GET, which would render the page server-side with the new theme settings (since your brain.php would be executed again and it would pull the most recent data from the database).

Comment: Well, I decided if I got the hang of Ajax, I would try to use it to update stats on my user menu as well. See, I'm constructing a social online rpg. I have some games that will update the user's points if they win. The members don't see this change immediately so they think that the points didn't update. I was hoping to fix this by possibly reloading brain.php when situations like this happen and not the current page. Same concept goes for my question. I'd like the changes to be made on the screen as they update.

Comment: Also I would like to add the fact that brain.php is only what determines the stats on the user menu, div names of my layout based on theme, small functions, and other various things. It's not really a big script. It's basically the outline of my website.

Comment: OK, but please clarify. What does brain.php do exactly? It specifies the CSS file to use for a specific user? It hardcodes colours in <style> tags in returned HTML? We'd need to know that in order to find the best solution to update the theme dynamically.

Comment: brain.php basically checks if the user is logged in, set's div names based on theme, has functions I call in other scripts, and let's users see their current points/other stats related to them. It's basically just the UI, with some small exceptions(functions). I would also like to add that the theme system only uses one css file, just different divs.

Comment: But does it render a single, discrete element like a <div> with stuff in it, or does it do more stuff? If it simply renders an element you can make an AJAX call, grab the returned HTML and update the existing page's div with the new contents.

Comment: brain.php also has functions like an achievement system that updates when conditions are satisfied. No direct code is being ran without conditions being met in brain.php.

Comment: Okay, I see. If it's just a matter of colours, why not simply have a CSS file per theme defining the properties for the themable controls? eg. if you have a 'blue' theme you'd have blue.css with stuff like div#cblue {border:5px solid dodgerBlue} and the 'pink' theme would have green.css with div#cblue {5px solid pink}. Then when user modifies profile or logs in you simply load the appropriate CSS file with javascript (example: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml).

Comment: Well it's not just the colors, it's also the virtual currency(fake of course), score(from achievements), and other member stats that I would like to be updated when changes are made. I meant to eventually clean up my css and the way it's used currently, but I'm constructing this project from scratch, and I'm trying to get core features done first. The site looked bad a few months ago, and it's still probably bad compared to other sites, but I'm doing the best I can being the only person programming. I like the method you spoke of, I'll look into it, but I'd still like brain updated on the fly.